# Can I get a single axis of a quaternion?

Tags: vector, geometry, quaternions, euler-angles

I would like to rotate a quaternion about a specific axis. I tried q_rot*q_original, with q_rot a constant quaternion:

```
double factor = sin( a / 2.0 );
double x = xx * factor;
double y = yy * factor;
double z = zz * factor;

double w = cos( a / 2.0 );

Quaternion(x, y, z, w).normalize();
```

But in my case, q_original changes over time and I think xx, yy, and zz should therefore be dependent on q_original (or the coordinate system of q_original). So I now would like to get the rotation axis directly from q_original. Does someone know how I get one axis e.g. the y_axis (3 components) from a quaternion (4 components)?

Edit: For each time stamp I have a position (x,y,z) and an orientation represented by a quaternion (x,y,z,w). I would like to rotate this pose(position, orientation). To rotate it I need the axis of rotation of that single pose. How can I get this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think that this is a C++17 question?

Comment: I want to do it in c++, but yes it is not specifically related to c++.

Comment: You don't rotate quaternions.  Quaternions can rotate geometry (points).  If you have a unit axis of rotation (x,y,z) and an angle a, then the quaternion to do that rotation is `(x*sin(a/2),y*sin(a/2),z*sin(a/2),cos(a/2))`

Comment: Or maybe you want something like `q_new = q_change * q_original`?

Comment: Yes I want something like this and I already tried this formula, but q_change has to be in the coordinate system of q_original I think. Because if I transform q_original with that formula the transformation does not stay constant for the next q_original. I have a q_original for t=0,1,2,3,.... and all off them should be rotated the same. If I use the x,y,z component of the current q_original as rotation axis, the transformation is constant for all t. So I would need now the right rotation axis, which is dependent of q_original. I would like to have the y_axis of q_original

Comment: If `q_yaxis = (0,1,0,0)` represents the Y axis, and you have q_original, then the Y axis rotated will be `q_original * q_yaxis * q_original.conjugate`.